# echo a variable with controller in prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

Salam every one

my english is not well

i develop a module of payment that have a controller named validation.php

this **validation.php**  validate payment and it has two status

the first if the payment is valide it must view **ok-ok-ok-ok**

and the second if the payment is not valid it must view **no-no-no-no**

in the web page, it must view this

`ok-ok-ok-ok`

or

`no-no-no-no`

this string must be viewed in page like a simple echo without html tags

i used the variable **content_only => true**  but it view in page source some tags that i dont need.

i hope that my question was clearly explained

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// Check that this payment option is still available in case the customer changed his address just before the end of the checkout process
    $res = 'NO NO';

    foreach (Module::getPaymentModules() as $module)
        if ($module['name'] == 'moduleName')
        {
            $res = 'ok ok';
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the header, footer and center column and ignore the left and right columns, then you can use the following code in your controller in initContent function

```
$this->display_column_left = true;
$this->display_column_right = true;
```

It will hide left and right column.If you need all contents to be hidden, then use

```
$this->content_only = true
```

But still remember that some basic html will be displayed at least the html start and end tags and some header basic html tags.

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean `display_column_left = false;`. Not true.